# Lots of database errors

Tags: drupal

Good evening, I am getting alot of errors when clicking on Mailings, Events, and Contributions. This all used to work before upgrading to 4.6.17. I am using this version as I am using Drupal 6, and PHP 5.5/6. Any quick suggestions?

An Example of this is here dealing with Mailings:

```
#0 /home/seal/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(182): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()
#1 [internal function](): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
#2 /home/seal/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(931): call_user_func((Array:2), Object(DB_Error))
#3 /home/seal/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB.php(979): PEAR_Error->PEAR_Error("DB Error: a515ac9c2796ca0e23adbe92c68fc9fc", "a515ac9c2796ca0e23adbe92c68fc9fc", 16, (Array:2), "\n            SELECT      civicrm_mailing.id,\n                        civicr...")
#4 /home/seal/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(564): DB_Error->DB_Error("a515ac9c2796ca0e23adbe92c68fc9fc", 16, (Array:2), "\n            SELECT      civicrm_mailing.id,\n                        civicr...")
#5 /home/seal/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1905): PEAR->raiseError(NULL, "a515ac9c2796ca0e23adbe92c68fc9fc", NULL, NULL, "\n            SELECT      civicrm_mailing.id,\n                        civicr...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#6 /home/seal/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(929): DB_common->raiseError("a515ac9c2796ca0e23adbe92c68fc9fc", NULL, NULL, NULL, "1055 ** Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains n...")
#7 /home/seal/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(403): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()
#8 /home/seal/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery("\n            SELECT      civicrm_mailing.id,\n                        civicr...")
#9 /home/seal/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2442): DB_common->query("\n            SELECT      civicrm_mailing.id,\n                        civicr...")
#10 /home/seal/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1634): DB_DataObject->_query("\n            SELECT      civicrm_mailing.id,\n                        civicr...")
#11 /home/seal/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(321): DB_DataObject->query("\n            SELECT      civicrm_mailing.id,\n                        civicr...")
#12 /home/seal/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1181): CRM_Core_DAO->query("\n            SELECT      civicrm_mailing.id,\n                        civicr...", TRUE)
#13 /home/seal/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Mailing/BAO/Mailing.php(2523): CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery("\n            SELECT      civicrm_mailing.id,\n                        civicr...", (Array:0))
#14 /home/seal/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Mailing/Selector/Browse.php(315): CRM_Mailing_BAO_Mailing->getRows(0, 50, Object(CRM_Utils_Sort), " AND civicrm_mailing.sms_provider_id IS NULL AND (civicrm_mailing.scheduled_i...", (Array:0))
#15 /home/seal/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Selector/Controller.php(403): CRM_Mailing_Selector_Browse->getRows(4, 0, 50, Object(CRM_Utils_Sort), 2, NULL)
#16 /home/seal/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Selector/Controller.php(340): CRM_Core_Selector_Controller->getRows(Object(CRM_Core_Selector_Controller))
#17 /home/seal/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Mailing/Page/Browse.php(233): CRM_Core_Selector_Controller->run()
#18 /home/seal/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(312): CRM_Mailing_Page_Browse->run((Array:4), NULL)
#19 /home/seal/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:15))
#20 /home/seal/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:4))
#21 /home/seal/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(360): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:4))
#22 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("mailing", "browse", "unscheduled")
#23 /home/seal/public_html/includes/menu.inc(350): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:3))
#24 /home/seal/public_html/index.php(17): menu_execute_active_handler()
#25 {main}
```

Comment: Are you using mysql version 5.7?

Comment: Yes, Server version: 5.7.27 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using very old and unsecured version of Civi I would recommend you to upgrade CiviCRM. I have tested it for 4.7.31 and its working fine provided you have certain modules that are compatible on CiviCRM 4.6 or less. The other alternate approach is to turn off ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY for sql_mode of mysql

Comment: Perfect, upgrading to that version worked a treat! Must be an issue with the other version

Comment: so can you marked this as answered if it was useful